# AngularJS. ng-class out of sync with variable in $scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a question about using ng-class to change DOM class.
Most of the buttons work fine, except "Two Blink" button.
I have already called $scope.$digest, but the I can't see the effect on setTimeout 500ms. Why?

Any help is appreciated!

HTML Code

```
<html>
    <title>
        Angular Blink Test
    </title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <body ng-app='app'>
        <style>
            .bk_red  {background-color:red;}
            .bk_blue {background-color:blue;}
        </style>

        <div ng-class='{bk_red: isRed, bk_blue:!isRed}' ng-controller='myController'>
            <button ng-click='buttonClick0()'>Check</button>
            <button ng-click='buttonClick1()'>One Blink</button>
            <button ng-click='buttonClick2()'>Two Blink</button>
            <button ng-click='buttonClick3()'>HTTP</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript Code

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    // this function is strict...

    var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.isRed = false;

        $scope.buttonClick0 = function () {
            alert('isRed=' + $scope.isRed);
        };

        $scope.buttonClick1 = function () {
            $scope.isRed = !$scope.isRed;
            console.log('buttonClick1 isRed:', $scope.isRed);
        };

        $scope.buttonClick2 = function () {
            $scope.isRed = !$scope.isRed;
            console.log('buttonClick2 isRed-1:', $scope.isRed);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $scope.isRed = !$scope.isRed;   //change again, but NOT working!
                $scope.$digest;  //I guess something else should be done here.
                console.log('buttonClick2 isRed-2:', $scope.isRed);
            }, 500);
        };

        $scope.buttonClick3 = function () {
            $scope.isRed = !$scope.isRed;
            console.log('buttonClick3 isRed-1:', $scope.isRed);
            $http(
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/data.js'
                }).
                then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.isRed = !$scope.isRed;
                    console.log('buttonClick3 isRed-2:', $scope.isRed);
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    $scope.isRed = !$scope.isRed;
                    console.log('buttonClick3 isRed-3:', $scope.isRed);
                });
        }
    });
}());
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/z1DGyAvZMKP3zgoqSawH?p=preview

Comment: Use $interval or $timeout instead. And be sure to call cancel() when your scope is destroyed.

Comment: Yes, $timeout will work. But I am using setTimeout to simulate some other thread job.

Comment: Is there a way not to use $interval or $timeout?
I want to enforce Angular.JS to check dirty again for everything.

Comment: It calls setTimeout under the hood, but it handles all the digest stuff for you. If you're going to insist on setTimeout, you should still cancel it because you will get a memory leak.

Comment: Using $interval or $timeout will force angular to check dirty again. That's what they are for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call $scope.$digest() rather than $digest if you want to kick off a digest cycle.

The proper thing to do, though, is to use $timeout instead of setTimeout. That will properly apply changes inside the angular digest cycle.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works on the test code. Thanks again!